# What is an act of cutting off useless words?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a verb (idiom?) that means an act of making speech/writing more terse/concise/laconic. Is there any?

Comment: We *cut* a written work, reduce its length; but you can't *cut* impromptu speech because once it's uttered it can't be changed -- you can only paraphrase it more briefly. (You can however *cut* a recording or transcript of impromptu speech.)

Comment: A good idiom would be "to trim the fat" off the sentence, speech, etc.

Comment: Some possibilities are: *to condense* (the passage), *to edit down* (the passage), *to abridge* (the passage, said of a longer written work), or *to cut out the useless words (verbiage,* from the passage).

Comment: @StewC Put that as an answer. Please don't answer in the comments.

Comment: I was doing that before, but I recently read in a meta-post that if we give answers with no explanations it's supposed to be in a comment instead... Does this mean it is a controversial issue?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to express what you want, including what people have already suggested: ***abridge***, ***condense***, ***cut***, ***edit down***, ***summarize***, ***trim the fat***

> To ***cut to the chase***

This means to stop meandering logically and express the big idea you are trying to express.

> To ***boil things down***

This means to take a lot of ideas and facts and notions and "boil away" the fat. What you are left with are just the most important ideas.

> To ***get to the heart of the matter***

This means to skip full discussion of a topic and talk immediately about the most important, central aspect of an issue.

> ***In a nutshell***

This phrase means you are going to summarize the significance of something.